# How to set GPS coordinates of Image?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, gps, javax.imageio

I want to set latitude and longitude of Image for an application in JAVA. Please share some resourceful information with me.

Thank you for your time.

[image]

I want to set like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [Apache commons imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/).

```
/**
 * This example illustrates how to add/update EXIF metadata in a JPEG file.
 * 
 * @param jpegImageFile
 *            A source image file.
 * @param dst
 *            The output file.
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws ImageReadException
 * @throws ImageWriteException
 */
public void changeExifMetadata(final File jpegImageFile, final File dst)
        throws IOException, ImageReadException, ImageWriteException {

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dst);
            OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);) {

        TiffOutputSet outputSet = null;

        // note that metadata might be null if no metadata is found.
        final ImageMetadata metadata = Imaging.getMetadata(jpegImageFile);
        final JpegImageMetadata jpegMetadata = (JpegImageMetadata) metadata;
        if (null != jpegMetadata) {
            // note that exif might be null if no Exif metadata is found.
            final TiffImageMetadata exif = jpegMetadata.getExif();

            if (null != exif) {
                // TiffImageMetadata class is immutable (read-only).
                // TiffOutputSet class represents the Exif data to write.
                //
                // Usually, we want to update existing Exif metadata by
                // changing
                // the values of a few fields, or adding a field.
                // In these cases, it is easiest to use getOutputSet() to
                // start with a "copy" of the fields read from the image.
                outputSet = exif.getOutputSet();
            }
        }

        // if file does not contain any exif metadata, we create an empty
        // set of exif metadata. Otherwise, we keep all of the other
        // existing tags.
        if (null == outputSet) {
            outputSet = new TiffOutputSet();
        }

        {
            // Example of how to add a field/tag to the output set.
            //
            // Note that you should first remove the field/tag if it already
            // exists in this directory, or you may end up with duplicate
            // tags. See above.
            //
            // Certain fields/tags are expected in certain Exif directories;
            // Others can occur in more than one directory (and often have a
            // different meaning in different directories).
            //
            // TagInfo constants often contain a description of what
            // directories are associated with a given tag.
            //
            final TiffOutputDirectory exifDirectory = outputSet.getOrCreateExifDirectory();
            // make sure to remove old value if present (this method will
            // not fail if the tag does not exist).
            exifDirectory.removeField(ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_APERTURE_VALUE);
            exifDirectory.add(ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_APERTURE_VALUE,
                    new RationalNumber(3, 10));
        }

        {
            // Example of how to add/update GPS info to output set.

            // New York City
            final double longitude = -74.0; // 74 degrees W (in Degrees East)
            final double latitude = 40 + 43 / 60.0; // 40 degrees N (in Degrees
            // North)

            outputSet.setGPSInDegrees(longitude, latitude);
        }

        // printTagValue(jpegMetadata, TiffConstants.TIFF_TAG_DATE_TIME);

        new ExifRewriter().updateExifMetadataLossless(jpegImageFile, os,
                outputSet);
    }
}
```

There are a lot of examples [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/imaging/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/imaging/examples/WriteExifMetadataExample.java)